# CSS padding в процентах от другого элемента

Tags: css, jquery

У меня есть span у которого задан: `padding: 3% 5%;`, также есть другой span где padding задан точно также, но поскольку ширина родителей в данном случае разная, то и padding получается другим, подскажите как сделать отступы одинаковыми фактически. Желательно на CSS, но можно и на Jquery

Comment: Задайте их в vw - тогда паддинги будут зависеть от ширины экрана и всегда будут между собой одинаковые

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @humster_spb Вообще, тут не очевидно совсем, что паддинги должны меняться вместе с шириной вьюпорта (окна браузера), т.к. нигде не указана ширина элемента в %. На практике обычно привязываются к текущему размеру шрифта с помощью единиц `em` или `rem`

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, раз отступы заданы в %, логично предположить, что они должны как-то меняться вместе с шириной окна браузера. Иначе их можно было просто в px задать.

Comment: @humster_spb понимаю, что меня никто не спрашивал, но задавать размер шрифта (как и отступы элементов с текстом) в пикселях — не самый лучший тон, это делает поведение верстки более непредсказуемым на разных устройствах

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov, поэтому, если Вы обратили внимание, я и не предложил автору вопроса вариант с px